# Efficient way to write platform specific UI in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to write an **efficient** platform specific UI in flutter. I know that I can use `Platform.isIOS` to detect if the platform is iOS and same for others, but checking for the platform for many widgets is cumbersome.

Is there any other way where I can avoid those checks and also is efficient at the same time ?

Comment: Some widgets have `.adaptive` constructor. You could write a similar wrapper class.

Comment: Yes but only some widgets like ```switch``` widget has it but i am asking what should be the method if there is no ```.adaptive``` method for a widget

Comment: Did you get my point?

Answer (score 1):

You should used package  : [flutter_platform_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets)

Simplifying the use of both Material and Cupertino widgets with a single widget
example : [Example of flutter_platform_widgets package](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4968762-platform-aware-widgets-in-flutter)

Comment: Yes you are correct but that library also doesn’t provide cross-platform versions for every widget. I was looking for some code examples that can be used for every widget without any library as libraries can have such limitations

Comment: you should create sperate Widget and it's widget manages automatically. For Example, create PlatformButton widget which checks platform and display UI according to the platform. Now, You should use this PlatformButton widget in all app so no need to check every time  for Platform.